# What does vanishing of higher direct images of the structure sheaf tell us?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

Let $f:X\to Y$ be a morphism of schemes over $k$. I am wondering about, what geometric consequences $R^qf_*O_X=0$ for $q\geq k$ does have. I saw vanishing of higher direct images used in some proofs of coherence of structure sheaves and also for the computation of cohomology if one in addition assumes that $f_*O_X=O_Y$. Also there seem to be a lot of papers out there discussing cases in which the higher direct images vanish for $q\geq 1$.

What are natural situations in which one wants vanishing of higher direct images and what does it tell us (geometrically)?

I know this is kind of vague but I was unable to figure it out myself. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I mean, as an example if $f:X\to Y$ is a smooth proper map of schemes over $\mathbb{C}$ then $R^1 f_\ast\mathcal{O}_X=0$ implies that $H^1_\mathrm{sing}(X_y,\mathbb{C})=0$ for each $y\in Y$. Is that the kind of thing you're thinking of?

Comment: @AlexYoucis Thank you for you comment. I'm not thinking of anything specific but curious what kind of results is implied by vanishing of higher direct images. So yes, your comment is precisely the kind of thing I was looking for (but I hope for more comments/answers so that I can see a bit of the variety of things one needs such vanishing results for).